# Optimising where clause with x in y or z in y

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm just wondering if there is any way to optimise this query :

```
 select * from table_x where buyer_id in (select id from table_y) x or 
seller_id in (select id from table_y) y
```

Since the two subqueries in my where-clause are identical and I suspect that the program will run the two subqueries separately

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is essentially:

```
select x.*
from table_x x
where x.buyer_id in (select y.id from table_y y) or
      x.seller_id in (select y.id from table_y y);
```

This construct should be fine.  In some databases, you might use `exists` instead of `in`, but I think Hive will be fine with this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Does it mean that internally hive has optimised (select y.id from table_y y) in a sense that it won't repeat the subquery?

Comment: @chrishendra93 . . . It will probably "repeat" the query, but that won't really affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

To solve multiple equery issue in hive use [semi left join](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins):

```
SELECT x.*
FROM table_x x
LEFT SEMI JOIN table_y b ON (x.buyer_id = b.id )
LEFT SEMI JOIN table_y c ON (x.seller_id = c.id )
```